# Is it possible transform JSON objects to beautiful views html.erb in ruby/rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, view

Imagine that I have this:

```
[ 
  {"id":1, "name":"bla", "other":"aaaa"},
  {"id":2, "name":"ble", "other":"eeee"},
  {"id":3, "name":"bli", "other":"iiii"},
]
```

I would like to see that in my someview.html.erb

```
Id:1
name:Bla
other:aaaa

Id:2
name:Ble
other:eee
```

...

When I say JSON, I mean that I dont know the object attributes. I just wanna format the JSON automagically.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
require 'JSON'
require 'yaml'

x = '[
  {"id":1, "name":"bla", "other":"aaaa"},
  {"id":2, "name":"ble", "other":"eeee"},
  {"id":3, "name":"bli", "other":"iiii"}
]'

puts JSON.parse(x).to_yaml
```